# Provider npm does not support features install_options

Tags: node.js, npm, puppet, httpserver, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to install a node package globally via package provider of puppet. Unforturnately it doesn't support install_options. I am getting the following error.

```
Debug: /Package[npm-http-server]: Provider npm does not support features install_options; not managing attribute install_option
Debug: /Package[npm-http-server]: Provider npm does not support features virtual_packages; not managing attribute allow_virtual
```

My manifest looks like below

```
class profiles::app::base::nodejs {
  class { 'nodejs':
    target_dir => '/bin',
    version => 'v8.9.4',
  }
  package { 'npm-http-server':  
    name => 'http-server',
    provider => 'npm',
    install_options => ['-g', { '--prefix' => '/'}],
    require  => Class['nodejs']
  }
}
```

**Operating System :** Centos 7 (with vagrant on windows 10)

**User** : Admin

**Module version** : mod 'willdurand-nodejs', '2.0.2'

**Puppet** : Masterless puppet version 4.10.12

My aim is to install the module globally in **/lib/node-modules/** folder and to create symlinks in **/bin** folder.

Am i doing it in wrong way? Any workaround /fix?

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be an issue with `Puppet` / Windows=> https://ask.puppet.com/question/33099/puppet-install_options-is-not-working-on-windows/

Comment: In my case, I am using CentOS 7

Comment: So you are saying that you do not get the desired result if you simply omit the `install_options` (and `allow_virtual`) parameters?

Comment: [The docs for willdurand/nodejs](https://forge.puppet.com/willdurand/nodejs) describe an alternative mechanism for managing npm packages that should be installed other than in the default location (`::nodejs::npm` resources).  Does that also not meet your needs?

Comment: No. I can install to a custom location. But again, I need to take care of syslinks manually. I want to install a module globally.